# Firefox Singleton Lock

Tags: firefox

I have essentially the same question as here:

[Ubuntu Firefox it is saying that it is already running but not responding](https://superuser.com/questions/78917/ubuntu-firefox-it-is-saying-that-it-is-already-running-but-not-responding)

But I found that the selected response doesn't work for me.  There is no parent.lock in the default folder.  There was a lock file; I deleted it, but I still have the error.

I don't have enough rep to comment, hopefully it's OK to ask like this.

Comment: Could you provide us some more information? Things like operating system version, Firefox version, if your user account has admin rights, when it started, the last change you can remember making before the issue presented, or any other relevant information? You might also want to try and add more relevant tags to your question to increase the visibility of your question :)

Comment: Check this official article in case you didn't already: ["Firefox is already running but is not responding" error message - How to fix it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-already-running-not-responding).

Comment: The accepted answer is just the one that worked for the author of the other question.  What about all of the other answers there?