# Open a new tab/window in an existing Firefox instance on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox

I would like to open a URL from the command line and have this open as a new tab or window in an already running and responding instance of Firefox.  I'm using Debian's Sid branch.  If I do the following:

In term 1:

```
$ firefox
```

In term 2:

```
$ firefox 'http://www.google.com'
```

**Update**: I've also tried -new-tab and -new-window, but I get the same result.

```
$ firefox -new-tab 'http://www.google.com'
```

I get the message:

```
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, 
you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
```

This has been discussed before (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/78917/ubuntu-firefox-it-is-saying-that-it-is-already-running-but-not-responding) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/553066/firefox-is-already-running-with-no-remote)), however, I do not want to kill the existing instance of Firefox (it's doing just fine) and I don't want to use a different profile.  This works seamlessly with Google Chrome.

Comment: If Firefox is your default browser, you can use `xdg-open`, which opens any file with its associated application.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `--new-window` or `--new-tab` command line options:

```
firefox --new-window 'http://www.google.com'
firefox --new-tab 'http://www.google.com'
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/699127/firefox-command-line-arguments/699128#699128 and [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

> NOTE: firefox has switched to dash-dash -- style for the command line options.

Comment: Not sure why, but I get the same result with -new-tab/-new-window.

Comment: Maybe you have a preference setting that conflates them.

Comment: I tried moving the ~/.mozilla dir out of the way and have Firefox recreate the default config.  Same behavior.  Are there any other settings that might influence this behavior?

Comment: I think I discovered the culprit.  I have MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1 set in my init file.  Removing this fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: careful with the long options: they start with two dashes, such as: --new-tab

Comment: @woohoo Not according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options, it shows just a single dash.

Comment: @Barmar: That's fine, they keep changing them... on Linux it works with two dashes as well... which _is_ the standard with long command-line parameters. BTW, revert back the edit to your answer, I still see two dashes there in the first line of text.

Answer (score 3):

I have the following line in my init file:

```
export MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1
```

This effectively prevents Firefox from doing exactly what I was trying to do.  Removing this fixed the problem.

Comment: What is the init file you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: Note that setting `export MOZ_NO_REMOTE=0` instead is a [wrong track](https://superuser.com/a/1359864/388856), since both lines are synonyms. I got messed up with that XD

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `LaunchFireFox.sh` with the line below:

```
xargs -a ff_url.txt firefox -new-tab "$line"
```

In a separate file `ff_url.txt`:

```
http://www.google.com
```

and any additional web pages.

Answer (score 0):

### For those of us using ***Wayland***

This symptom might be due to wayland/xwayland issues ([firefox's buglist](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1645038)).

#### What worked for me:

I'm running Sway, with `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` set, and added the below to
`~/.config/environment.d/<my-sway-config>.conf`:

```
MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1
```

The above is equivalent to running the below inside a `bash` shell:

```bsh
export MOZ_DBUS_REMOTE=1
firefox
```

Thereafter, all links clicked in other programs opened up in Firefox without issues. As expected.
Thanks to [Martin Stransky](https://mastransky.wordpress.com/2020/03/16/wayland-x11-how-to-run-firefox-in-mixed-environment/) for getting me on the correct track!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new tab to open without a URL known yet, then `firefox --new-tab` (i.e. omitting a URL) will open a new window, which is probably not the desired behavior. Instead, use the following to open a new tab in the existing window (with the cursor set to the URL bar, so that you can enter your prompt right away):

```
firefox --new-tab about:newtab
```

This is a good command to use for a system-wide hotkey.