# "Firefox is already running, but is not responding." even though MOZ_NO_REMOTE=0

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, browser, browser-tabs

This is Debian 9 Stretch speaking, `#1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21)`, with a new, portable installation of Firefox 62.0 run from `/opt` with

```
$ which firefox
/opt/firefox/firefox
```

My problem is that, even though the command

```
$ firefox
```

does launch and run a firefox instance, a subsequent command

```
$ firefox any.kind/of/url
```

fails with the famous window message

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, 
>   you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

whereas it used to just open a new tab for the provided url in the existing, running session.

The options `--new-tab`, `--new-window` or `--no-remote` do not help. And I have checked according to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/829232/388856), that

```
$ echo $MOZ_NO_REMOTE
0
```

.. which I think should mean that my desired behaviour is the expected behaviour. (Note that it is not clear to me what is the `init` file they refer to in this post).

As (I-think-)related problems:

- clicking a link in a `.pdf` file opened with `evince` also fails with the same error message.
- cliking a link in an e-mail viewed in thunderbird also fails with the same error message.

Am I missing anything here?
How do I add a new tab to the running browser session from the command line?
Any way to solve / get around this problem?

Comment: Are you running your second copy of `firefox` using the same user in the same X session?

Comment: As a data point, I tested this with Ubuntu 18.04, which is based on Debian 10 Buster, and Firefox v62 installed from the Ubuntu repo (not portable).  It worked as intended ("firefox URL" opens the URL in a new tab of the open Firefox).  That would seem to narrow it down to the portable version of Firefox and/or Firefox's behavior in Debian 9.

Comment: @kostix Yes I am. Both commands are send from two neighbouring terminal emulators.

Comment: @fixer1234 Cheers :)

Comment: Another data point: On my Debian Stretch, Firefox ESR works just fine with `--new-tab`: it says an already running copy to open the specified URL in a new tab. That's 60.2.0esr (amd64) from the official repo (now as a security update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it. According to [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1175106), the actual value of `MOZ_NO_REMOTE` environment variable does not matter, only the fact that it is *defined* or not. So `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=0` is suprisingly *synonym* of `MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1`.

So after I removed this line

```
export MOZ_NO_REMOTE=0
```

that somehow sneaked into my `.[bash|zsh]rc` files, and checked that

```
$ echo $MOZ_NO_REMOTE
⠀
```

I got my good ol' behaviour back :)