# Firefox behaving aways like in no-remote mode in WSLg/Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, ubuntu-22.04

I have a shell script that opens several tabs in default browser for 2fa process (indirectly by using `aws sso login`). This script runs in WSL2/Ubuntu 22.04.

Now this is interesting: The behavior is always same, like it would run by default in no-remote mode: first tab opens fine, all the subsequent will fail with "Firefox is already running but is not responding...". Seems second call to firefox is always launching a new instance instead of connecting to existing one. The same happens if I'll try to just start firefox twice from console while it is already running. If I use different profiles then it works.  [It behaves same as in here](https://superuser.com/questions/1359648/firefox-is-already-running-but-is-not-responding-even-though-moz-no-remote-0) except the fact that $MOZ_NO_REMOTE is not set at all.

Things already checked:

- `$MOZ_NO_REMOTE` is not set, not zero, not empty string, just not set
- deleted `~/.mozilla/firefox`, it created a fresh profile but still same behavior immediately as soon as second link is opened.
- after closing firefox there are no zombies left
- there is only one firefox installation in Ubuntu in `/usr/bin/firefox` using apt
- This was fine several months ago (many wsl2 and Ubuntu updates ago)

**Update:** experimented a bit and if I launch firefox as superuser then this works as expected, I will get two tabs/windows with a single pid